# Configure CircleCI for Maven project using Nexus repo

Tags: java, maven, nexus, circleci, sonatype

I'm using external `Nexus` repository for java maven project and I trying to config circleCI config. At first I need to somehow say `CircleCI` to look into env variables for credentials during build.
In `grade` driven java projects all going fine without any extra configs, but in `maven` it says that can't have access to nexus.
Have anybody experience with it?
It's my first time configuring CircleCI

**UPD1:**

For authorisation I added env variables for `username`, `password`, `server url` and `attributes` to context on CircleCI Organization Settings page

I using [this](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/sonatype/nexus-platform-orb) ORB and there I have found the names of env variables I have to use as default names.

Created `circleci` config file:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  nexus-platform-orb: sonatype/nexus-platform-orb@1.0.28

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - nexus-platform-orb/nexusjob:
          context: MyContext
```

And have this error:

```
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/workspace (Is a directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/workspace (Is a directory)
    at NexusPublisher.run(NexusPublisher.groovy:59)

Exited with code exit status 1
```

But when I added `command` to create file inside and used it, I steel have the same problem.
***For a which file or directory circleci is looking for?***

**UPD1:**

I a bit updated my config file:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.3.0
  nexus-platform-orb: sonatype/nexus-platform-orb@1.0.28

jobs:
  install-nexus:
    executor: nexus-platform-orb/nexus-platform-cli
    steps:
      - checkout
      - nexus-platform-orb/install

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - install-nexus
      - nexus-platform-orb/nexusjob:
          context: MyContext
          workspace: tmp/workspace/
          requires:
            - install-nexus
```

As a result I have an error running this job:

```
/bin/sh: curl: not found
```

Because command `nexus-platform-orb/install` contains this line:

```
curl -L
      https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-release-local/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-binary/<<
      parameters.groovy-version >>/groovy-binary-<< parameters.groovy-version
      >>.zip -o apache-groovy-binary.zip
```

But adding command installing `curl` gives me one another error:

```
steps:
      - checkout
      - run: apk update && apk add curl curl-dev bash
      - nexus-platform-orb/install
```

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
apk update && apk add curl curl-dev bash
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied

Exited with code exit status 99
```

And I have no idea how to fix it, because only way I found is to add `RUN root` to the `Dockerfile`. But it not works.

**UPD2:**

I spent more than week to understand how to fix it and posted my resolution as an answer.
Hope it will save time for someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution of this problem is to manually say what exactly file to use for getting credentials.

This is how my `config.yml` file looks after all:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.3.0

jobs:
  build:
    executor: maven/default
    working_directory: ~/my-project
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Test
          command: |
            mvn -s ./settings.xml clean test
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build
```

I do not need `nexus` orb anymore. I used `maven` orb for an `executor`.
Added command `mvn -s ./settings.xml clean test` to run tests and says in which file nexus credentials are.

`settings.xml` file:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>MYPROJECT</id>
            <username>*****</username>
            <password>*****</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

And link to `Nexus` repository I added in `pom.xml` file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id> MYPROJECT </id>
        <name>*****</name>
        <url>https://nexus.*****/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Hope this case will help someone.